# Is it necessary to restart Cassandra after updating its .truststore?

Tags: cassandra, ssl-certificate

We are using Cassandra with SSL encryption. We have added a new user and generated its key/certificate that was referenced from cqlshrc. However it didn't work until Cassandra was restarted. Is it always necessary to restart Cassandra on an update of truststore (certificates store) or is there another way how to tell Cassandra that there is a new certificate?

It is not clear from Cassandra documentation as the necessity of restart is mentioned just for changes in yaml.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although it was asked a long time ago I will post my answer for the record: yes, it is necessary to restart Cassandra after updating the trustore.

As far as I can see from the source code the Cassandra loads truststores at start only.